# Apple push notification info is missing when we clear the notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I have received push notification, if i open the push notification then didReceiveRemoteNotification is calling and i am getting the notification information, instead of if i clear the notifications and open the app then didReceiveRemoteNotification is not getting called. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the app from the launch icon (instead of opening it from the push notification), `didReceiveRemoteNotification` will not be called and you'll have no way to access the notification data. It doesn't matter if you clear the notifications or not.

> If the action button is tapped (on a device running iOS), the system launches the application and the application calls its delegate’s application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method (if implemented); it passes in the notification payload (for remote notifications) or the local-notification object (for local notifications).
>
> **If the application icon is tapped on a device running iOS, the application calls the same method, but furnishes no information about the notification**.

Answer (score 0):

As Eran pointed out, if You're opening the app from the Icon that callback will not be called. I don't know if the notification is totally removed when You delete it from the notification center list, but if the app is not running  and has been launched by tapping on the notification, you can check for the notification in the launchOptions at the startup:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary
*)launchOptions {
    NSDictionary *notif = [launchOptions objectForKey: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (notif) {
       //handle your notification here
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: The notification data is only passed to the app in the launchOptions if you launch the app by tapping the notification. If you launch the app with its launch icon, you won't get the notification data.

Comment: also reading [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Launch_Options_Keys), i see the description of `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey`: This key is also used to access the same value in the userInfo dictionary of the notification named UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification.

Comment: But I agree with You that this value will be empty if the app is launched from the icon.